# Error always on line 102 of my code

Tags: python, datetime, error-handling

So I am creating a module, and I am importing it to a python shell and running some stuff to make sure all features work and such.

For some reason every time I run the code, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ryansaxe/Desktop/Code/python/modules/pymaps.py", line 102, in url_maker
    #anything can be here
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

So where the `#anything can be here` is, is whatever is on line 102 of my code. Originally line 102 was:

```
if isinstance(startindex,datetime.datetime):
```

and I got the error above. I put a quick print statement on line 102 to check and it gave the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ryansaxe/Desktop/Code/python/modules/pymaps.py", line 102, in url_maker
    print 'Hello'
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Is this some sort of bug? Why is it telling me there is an error with datetime on the line `print 'Hello'`?

Because it may be helpful, I will give you the function I am having trouble with since I have no clue how this is possible. I am keeping the `print 'Hello'` line so you can see where line 102 is:

```
def url_maker(latitudes,longitudes,times=None,color='red',label=' ',zoom=12,center=None,start=None,end=None,by=None,size='600x300'):
    urls = []   
    import datetime
    if isinstance(times[0],str) or isinstance(times[0],datetime.datetime):
        from dateutil import parser
        if isinstance(times[0],str):
            times = [parser.parse(x) for x in times]
        if isinstance(start,str):
            startindex = parser.parse(start)
        else:
            startindex = start
        if isinstance(end,str):
            endindex = parse.parse(end)
        else:
            endindex = end
        print 'Hello'
        if isinstance(startindex,datetime.datetime):
            startpos = between_times(times,startindex,by='start')
        elif isinstance(startindex,int):
            if isinstance(endindex,datetime.datetime):
                startpos = between_times(times,endindex,by='end') - start
            else:
                startpos = start
        else:
            pass
        if isinstance(endindex,datetime.datetime):
            endpos = between_times(times,endindex,by='end')
        elif isinstance(endindex,int):
            if isinstance(startindex,datetime.datetime):
                endpos = between_times(times,startindex,by='start') + end
            else:
                endpos = end
        else:
            pass
    else:
        times = range(1,len(latitudes) + 1)
        if isinstance(start,int):
            startpos = start
        else:
            startpos = None
        if isinstance(end,int):
            endpos = end
        else:
            endpos = None
    if isinstance(by,str):
        lat,lon,t = latitudes[startpos:endpos],latitudes[startpos:endpos],times[startpos:endpos]
        print lat
        t,lats,lons = time_sample(t,by,lat,lon)
    elif isinstance(by,int):
        lats,lons,t = latitudes[startpos:endpos:by],latitudes[startpos:endpos:by],times[startpos:endpos:by]
    else:
        lats,lons,t= latitudes[startpos:endpos],latitudes[startpos:endpos],times[startpos:endpos]
    print t
    print len(t)
    if center == None:
        latit = [str(i) for i in lats]
        longi = [str(i) for i in lons]
        center = '&center=' + common_finder(latit,longi)
    else:
        center = '&center=' + '+'.join(center.split())
    zoom = '&zoom=' + str(zoom)
    for i in range(len(lats)):
        #label = str(i)
        x,y = str(lats[i]),str(lons[i])
        marker = '&markers=color:' + color + '%7Clabel:' + label + '%7C' + x + ',' + y
        url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&size=' + size + zoom + center + marker + '&sensor=true'
        urls.append(url)
        #print i
    return urls,t
```

Comment: Boil your code down to a smaller reproducing example.  I bet somewhere you have `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: yeah I had that in the shell previously for testing something out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running with a stale bytecode cache or are re-running the code in an existing interpreter without restarting it.

The traceback code has only bytecode to work with, which contains filename and linenumber information. When an exception occurs, the source file is loaded to retrieve the original line of code, but if the source file has changed, that leads to the wrong line being shown.

Restart the interpreter and/or remove all `*.pyc` files; the latter will be recreated when the interpreter imports the code again.

As for your specific exception; you probably imported the `datetime` class from the `datetime` module somewhere:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

The `datetime` class does not have a `datetime` attribute, only the module does.